# <iframe> is loading three times even if it is used for only once in code in angular 2

Tags: angular

[app.component.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khpW2.png)

[app.component.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9W37.png)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prchU.png)

I have used this code on multiple computer, but showing the same output as    iframe is loading thrice and the html file to which it is marked with is not loading also. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Html code is : <div>
    <iframe style="background-color: blueviolet" width="100%" height="300" [src]="url"></iframe>
 </div>

Comment: Add the relevant code to the question and show only output as image. See how to post a [mcve].

Comment: Cant you paste actual code insteed of screenshots ?? Event better, prepare stackblitz